# C#: Protected Variables inside of a Generic Class can be accessed by a different subclass of that Generic Class. Can I prevent this?

Tags: c#, generics, singleton, generic-programming

Say I have a generic class Foo, that has a variable that is protected

```
public class Foo<T> 
{ 
    protected bool knowsFu; 
}
```

I also have 2 sub-classes: Bar and Pipe

```
public class Bar : Foo<Bar> {}

public class Pipe : Foo<Pipe> {}
```

It is actually possible for me to access the knowsFu in Pipe FROM Bar, e.g.:

```
public class Bar : Foo<Bar> 
{
    void UpdateFuInOtherClass(Pipe p)
    {
        p.knowsFu = false;
    }
}
```

Is this intended behaviour? (If so, what would be the usecase?)

Is there a way for me to prevent other Foo-Subclasses from modifying/reaching the protected variable inside of my current subclass?

**More specifically:** I'm using a generic class to implement the Singleton-Pattern:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

However, I'm currently able to access any singleton's protected instance-variable, as long as I am inside of another Singleton. Is there a way to prevent this?

EDIT: It might be relevant to note that the protected variable (knowsFu) is actually STATIC as well.

**EDIT2: Ok, maybe the example was abit too generic.. here's how I'm actually currently implementing it:**

*why use Singleton? A:The platform I'm working on is Unity3D, in which the pattern is used frequently*

I have a generically typed abstract class SingletonBehaviour

```
public abstract class SingletonBehaviour<T> where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static T Instance { get { return instance; } }

    protected static T instance { get; private set; } }

    // Loading is done through Unitys Awake-Method
}
```

One of the Singleton-Objects that I'm using is the APIManager

```
public class APIManager : SingletonBehaviour<APIManager>
{
    // Methods like SendHTTPPost(), HTTPGet(), etc.
}
```

However, since most of my projects need some better API-implementation than that, what I'm currently doing is:

```
public class ProjectAAPIManager : APIManager 
{
    // Overriding Instance so my return value is not APIManager but instead ProjectAAPIManager
    public static new ProjectAAPIMamager Instance { get { return (ProjectAAPIManager)instance; } }
}
```

This ^ is the reason my (inner) instance-variable is protected, and not private.

However, because of this, any other SingletonBehaviour in my project can now access the (inner) instance-variable on my ProjectAAPIManager

```
public class GameController : SingletonBehaviour<GameController> 
{
    private void AMethod()
    {
         // Accessing inner variable instead of public one
         ProjectAAPIManager.instance.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

As it's only the getter, this currently does not really matter. But what if I'd need access to the setter in my subclass as well?

*Also: would it be worth it to generically type my APIManager as well?*

Comment: `protected bool knowsFu { get; private set; }` ?

Comment: Yeah.. That's what I'm using now.. However, what if I need a protected (inner) set as well?

Comment: _"A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances."_

Answer (score 0):

You should not have classes that implement your generic singleton class.
Otherwise, by default, your protected fields will be accessible by the subclasses (it's what "protected" keyword does)

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var barInstance = Foo<Bar>.GetInstance();
    }
}

public class Foo<T> where T : new()
{
    protected bool knowsFu;

    private static T _instance;

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new T();

        return _instance;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

To use a singleton, you should not make another class implement the singleton behavior (This is not how the singleton pattern works).
To use the same classes as your second example, you should do something like this.

```
public class SingletonBehaviour<T> where T : new()
{    
    public static T Instance 
    { 
        get 
        {
            if(instance == null)
                instance = new T()
            return instance; 
        } 
    } 
    private static T instance { get; set; } 
}

public class APIManager // This class should not inherit from the SingletonBehavior class
{
    // Methods like SendHTTPPost(), HTTPGet(), etc.
}

public class ProjectAAPIManager : APIManager 
{
    public ProjectAAPIManager GetInstance() => SingletonBehavior<ProjectAAPIManager>.Instance();
}
```

Comment: the knowsFu is actually the _instance in my case..
I have a 'generic' API-manager, that has things like my accesskey, HTTPPost-methods, etc. This class inherits my Singleton-GenericClass

public class APIManager : SingletonBehaviour<APIManager>{}

However, this functionality is used in multiple of my projects. I thus have a
public class ProjectAAPIManager : APIManager {}
This means that the public Instance-variable in ProjectAAPIManager is actually of type APIManager, not ProjectAAPIManager. The way I'm currently handling this is with a public new PAAPIM Instance { return (PAAPIM)_inst}

Comment: I updated my answer with your examples. I think the problem is your usage of the singleton class. In a singleton, your instance should be private. You should only have a public property that will return your instance if it exists, or create a new one if it doesn't. Hope this helps!

Comment: Inheriting from Singleton is the recommended/advised implementation here, as Unity-Objects (scripts) do not have constructors. They are usually created through a call to AddComponent<ClassType>(). See http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton

Answer (score 0):

Your question is nothing short of bewildering. How can you make a protected member not be accesible from a derived class? Well, a good start is not making it protected.

`protected` is by definition exactly what you don't want, so don't use it! Use private instead.

If what you are asking is how to make it a readonly member when accessed from derived types, you have two options:

1. Declare it as readonly in the base class if possible.
2. Use a protected property instead with a private setter.

Many novice coders seems to think protected members aren't part of the public surface of the type but they really are, as long as the class can be extended. As such, the rules of public members apply: never expose public fields unless they are readonly or constants, use properties instead.

Comment: 1. Can't. Since I'm using Unity3D, Initialization is done in the Awake()-method, as there is no Constructor.

Comment: 2. (Won't let me newline for some reason): That is my current solution. However, what if my subclass would need set-access as well?

Comment: That would make it accessible from ANY of my singletons though, not the subclass itself only.

Comment: @FrankvHoof Yes, but the fact that you want derived types to access different members seems like a pretty bad code smell unless the distinction is between classes *you* or *your* team are implementing (same assembly) and future public consumers. In that case you can use the `private protected` access modifier (you need C# 7.2).

Comment: @FrankvHoof Then use `internal`. Yes, any class in your assembly can see the member but you control the implementation so its not really a problem exposing what should be protected members; if you don't trust the coders working in your assembly you've got bigger problems to solve.

Comment: My APIManager isn't actually in the same assembly either, as it's in a (company-created) utilities-dll. Otherwise I could just adapt the actual APIManager-class for each project instead of inheriting from it. (Edit: nvm that's still the same assembly)